# Pageable realtime search with ReactiveUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have an interface that I add to my ViewModel when I need my view to be pageable

```
public interface IPageable
{
    Task LoadNextPage();
    bool IsLoadingPage { get; set; }
}
```

I then attach a `PageableBehavior` to my `ListView`, and whenever my ListView reaches the bottom of the page, it calls `IPageable.LoadNextPage();` on the ViewModel. (note: I've got all of this working when not using ReactiveUI)

My problem is that although I can easily react to search terms, I can not seem to figure out how to also load the next page in a Reactive way into `_searchResults`.

```
public class SeedSelectionViewModel : ReactiveObject, IPageable
{
    private const int PageSize = 30;
    private const int Threshold = 3;
    private static readonly TimeSpan _throttle = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    private readonly ISeedInputDataService _dataService;
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IEnumerable<SeedVarietySeed>> _searchResults;

    public SeedSelectionViewModel(ISeedInputDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
            .Throttle(_throttle)
            .Select(term => term?.Trim())
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Where(term => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term) && term.Trim().Length >= Threshold)
            .SelectMany((searchText,count,token) => SearchSeedVarieties(searchText,0))
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, nameof(SearchResults), out _searchResults);
    }

    [Reactive] public string SearchText { get; set; }

    [Reactive] public bool IsLoadingPage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SeedVarietySeed> SearchResults => _searchResults.Value;

    private Task<IEnumerable<SeedVarietySeed>> SearchSeedVarieties(string searchText, int skip) 
        => _dataService.FindSeedVarieties(searchText, skip, PageSize, CancellationToken.None);

    public Task LoadNextPage()
    {
        // how do I load additional results into _searchResults?
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble here is that you cannot use `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` in this way. You cannot change it from two different subscriptions.

The correct way to handle it is to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` or similar, and call `InvokeCommand` from the `WhenAnyValue`

```
ctor()
{
    _loadDataCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string>(LoadData);

    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
            .Throttle(_throttle)
            .Select(term => term?.Trim())
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Where(term => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term) && term.Trim().Length >= Threshold)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .InvokeCommand(_loadDataCommand);
}

private async Task LoadData(string searchText)
{
    var result = await _dataService.FindSeedVarieties(searchText, 0, PageSize, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(true);
    SearchResults.ReplaceRange(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Please do not forget to accept your answer.

Comment: gotta wait a couple days